# How to make a method with a Q.Promise and catch clause type check

Tags: typescript

I have the following method:

```
class A {

  m(): Q.Promise<MyObject> {
    return someAsyncOp()
        .then(x => transformX(x))
        .catch(err => {
          log.error(err);
          throw err; // <-- doesn't type check
        })
  }
}
```

What I would like to accomplish was to get this method typechecking. So far it appears as it expects the catch block to return something of the type parameterized in the Promise.

This is strange since a method can either return or throw and so in my mind this should type check.

Without the `catch` clause it type checks. With the catch clause compilation fails with the error `Type Q.Promise<void> is not assignable to Q.Promise<MyObject>`. This error leads me to believe that the compiler expects me to return a value in the catch clause, which as far as I know, I'm not obligated to do.

Is there a way to make this type check? Am I doing something wrong or does Typescript not support what I'm attempting to do?

**Typescript compiler version 1.8.10**

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong or does TypeScript not support what I'm attempting to do

You are doing nothing wrong. The `catch` scenarios are completely un-typechecked.

## Reason

Literally *anything* can cause an error that would make its way to `catch`. Essentially TypeScript does not go down the java path of forcing you to declare your `throws` at each point

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying there is no way that that code will compile without throwing errors, correct?

Comment: No. What I am saying is that `throw` is not type checked. It will compile fine.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that the .js files are generated, but there are compilation errors. I don't call that "compile fine". Guess I'll have to use `Q.Promise<any>`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So a teacher of mine explained it to me. Apparently it's as simple as parameterizing the lambda expression:

```
class A {

  m(): Q.Promise<MyObject> {
    return someAsyncOp()
        .then(x => transformX(x))
        .catch((err): MyObject => { // <-- Now everything compiles fine.
          log.error(err);
          throw err; 
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: The `.catch()` here doesn't return a `MyObject` type. You're faking it, thus it's not "as simple as", it's a hack you provided, not a solution.

Comment: The catch doesn't have to return a `MyObject`. It can either return that type or throw an error, both are valid for keeping the promise contract. Not even going to comment on the hack VS solution accusation, rofl!

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that throwing an error doesn't correspond to returning a `MyObject`, you are basically casting the return type, thus it doesn't make sense. Casting the wrong type to silence an error is as useful as doing plain JavaScript.

Comment: You can type `never` if you intend to throw.